# how to find distinct digit set numbers over a range of integers?

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose i have a unsigned integer, call it low and one another call it high such that high>low.
The problem is to find distinct digit set numbers over this range.
For example, suppose low is 1 and high is 20 then the answer is 20, because all the numbers in this range are of distinct digit sets. If suppose low is 1 and high is 21, then the answer is 20, because 12 and 21 have same digit set i.e.1, 2. I am not looking for a bruteforce algo., if anyone has a better solution then a usual bruteforce approach, please tell..

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The maximum n<=high where all numbers in the interval [low,n] have different digits? Or do you want the maximum size of an arbitrary subset of [low,high] with this property? Or something different?

Comment: I wish to have exact count of such numbers between low and high.

Comment: Are you after the algorithm or the code to do this?

Comment: @ChrisBD, so algorithm questions are either "send-me-teh-codez" or "off-topic"?

Comment: @evil.coder: you did not answer my question. Let's have an example: low = 123, high = 321: is the answer 131 (because 132 is the next number with the same digits), or 11 (=132-123), or 194 (because the interval [123,321] has 199 numbers, and when you remove 132, 213, 231, 312 and 321 there are 194 different numbers remaining)? And by the way, do you consider 12 and 122 having the same set of digits?

Comment: May be one more example will clear u. Take an example, low=121, high=321.the bruteforce approach is to start from 121 and eliminate numbers with same digit set (211 only) between low and high. Next is 122, possible eliminations are 221 ,  212. Next is 123 then 132, 213, 231, 312, 321 are not counted. Clearly 12 and 122 are distinct set because one contains 2 digits and another 3.

Comment: The answer is count of such numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There obviously is a mathematical answer to this, although I'll admit that I haven't worked it out as yet.

Simply put if the low = 1 and high = 99 then we have the following:

```
0 - 9 = 10 unique numbers
10-19 = 10 unique numbers
20-29 = 9 unique numbers
30-31 = 8 unique numbers
40-49 = 7 unique numbers
50-59 = 6 unique numbers
60-69 = 5 unique numbers
70-79 = 4 unique numbers
80-89 = 3 unique numbers
90-99 = 2 unique numbers
```

It would perhaps be easier to work out if we assumed that all numbers had to have the same number of digits, with leading zeros where required. For example 01, 02, 03, 04 for 1, 2, 3, 4. This would mean that 01 and 10 would match.
Then our number distribution changes to:

```
0 - 9 = 10 unique numbers
10-19 = 9 unique numbers
20-29 = 8 unique numbers
30-31 = 7 unique numbers
40-49 = 6 unique numbers
50-59 = 5 unique numbers
60-69 = 4 unique numbers
70-79 = 3 unique numbers
80-89 = 2 unique numbers
90-99 = 1 unique numbers
```

You can see that it should be possible to base a recursive formula on this using factors of 10 to determine how many unique numbers there may be.
The difficulty will be how to cope with the starting and ending points being variable e.g. low = 25 and high = 87.
Still this is a start, I'll think further on it.

Comment: Your examples are... strange. I think you messed up on the ranges. `10-19` = `{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}` which gives 10 unique numbers. Did you meant that `0-19` would only have `9` more numbers than `0-9` ?

Comment: @Matthieu - in the second example I was suggesting that we include a leading zero. Thus 01 and 10 are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally wrapped my head around the problem.

Let's take range `[low,high]` and put the numbers within this range in sets depending on their digits as such:

- "121" --> set "112"
- "122" --> set "122"
- "211" --> set "112"

We want to know the number of sets that will contain a unique element.

I would suggest that the simplest way to do this is actually... to do it like this.

```
def rangeCount(low, high):
  sets = defaultdict(list)
  for i in range(low, high+1):
    key = `i`.sort()            # obtain digits and sort them
    sets[key].append(i)

  count = 0
  for v in sets.values():
    if len(v) == 1: count = count + 1
  return count
```

Okay, it's bruteforce, but at least everybody should be on the same page now :)

Comment: I have already implemented this, but what if the range is 1 to 10 billion.how many sets are there? I was expecting someone will discover any mathematical series behind this.

Comment: They may, I just wrote it down so it would be easier for anyone coming up with something else to test its result.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, now I better understand the question (but I have no idea so far how to bring the complexity under O(high-low))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you started: 
[mathematic combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/combinations/article.php/c5117

Comment: I don't think this will help. If it is going right way, i wish to know how?

Comment: Are you after the algorithm or the code to do this? Oops sorry wrong place for my comment.